# How to pass params to static callback function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, static, callback, static-methods

I have code

MergeTool.as:

```
private static function askFromUser(cardId:uint, field:String, mainValue:*, addValue:*):void {

    WindowManager.instance.showQuestionPopup({
        message: "Client " + cardId + " has duplicate values. Do you want to replace" + mainValue + " to " + addValue,
        id:cardId,
        field:field,
        value:addValue
    }, okCallback);
}

private static function okCallback(p:*):void {
    trace("ok", p.message);
}
```

QuestionPopup.as :

```
private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(_ok) _ok.call(params);
}
```

When I press "Yes" it trows an error :

Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on core::MergeTool$/okCallback(). Expected 1, got 0.

But, if I use anonymous callback with 0 arguments - it works properly :

```
        WindowManager.instance.showQuestionPopup({
        message: "Client " + cardId + " has duplicate values. Do you want to replace" + mainValue + " to " + addValue,
        id:cardId,
        field:field,
        value:addValue
    }, function (){
        trace("ok", this.message);
    });
```

It returns params object, that I pass to  WindowManager.instance.showQuestionPopup(params, callback) and I can access it with "this" inside anonymous fucntion.

I think 1 variant doesn`t wokr because of static. How to fix 1 variant, because 2 is non intuitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `function.call()` method doesn't pass parameters, the argument is to tell what object `this` should refer to.

Instead, you should use the `function.apply(context, parameter array)` method.  It takes the same first parameter as the `call` method, but then the second parameter takes an `Array`and applies each element of the array as an argument to the function you want to call.  So for you, it should look like this:

```
private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if(_ok != null) _ok.apply(this, [params]);
}
```

To illustrate, let's say you have the following function that requires 3 parameters:

```
function test(p1:Number, p2Number, p3:Number){

}
```

The following two lines are exactly the same:

```
test(1,2,3);

test.apply(this, [1,2,3]);
```